# Search for all word pairs in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help with some VBA code which will look through a range of cells an pull out and list all word pairs which are separated by a space.

So this

[image]

would be output like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub F()

    Dim x, z, arr, cell

    For Each cell In [A1:A3]
        arr = Split(cell)
        For x = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
            z = z + 1
            Cells(z, 2) = arr(x) & " " & arr(x + 1)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```